# Is the cloudkms peak_qps metric correct?

Tags: google-cloud-kms

The Google Docs explain that the peak_qps Google Cloud Metric is the project's maximum per-second crypto request count but it always seems to read too high when I view it in the console using the Metrics Explorer. Am I mis-understanding what it represents?

If I do

- 3 decryptions every second the peak_qps is 40
- 1 decryption every second the peak_qps is 20
- 1 decryption every 5 seconds the peak_qps is 10
- 1 decryption every 10 seconds the peak_qps is 5
- 1 decryption every 20 seconds the peak_qps is 2.5

I was expecting 1 decryption every second to give me a qps of 1. And 1 decryption every 5 seconds would be a qps of 0.2. etc.